# regexp exec pattern before returns Null

Tags: javascript, regex

My test RegExp with pattern before returns null.  How do I get it to return 2?

```
s = new RegExp(/(?=ID\=)(\d+)/).exec("ID=2");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?=)` is a lookahead assertion. You'd want to use lookbehind, which JavaScript does not support. This, however, will work just fine:

```
s = /ID=(\d+)/.exec('ID=2')[1];
// or
s = new RegExp('ID=(\\d+)').exec('ID=2')[1];
```

Don't pass a regexp literal to the `RegExp` constructor — that just does not make sense.

Really, though, why wouldn't you just split on `=`?

```
s = 'ID=2'.split('=')[1];
```

Comment: javascript supports the (?=),the error is in your use  
"test".match(/\w+(?=\.)/); //null 
"test.".match(/\w+(?=\.)/); teste // works fine

Comment: I said nothing about JS not supporting lookahead.

Comment: I was following example from website below.  The syntax and description of this function is incorrect on the website.   http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

Comment: @user no, you read it incorrectly. The example on that site is `var phonenumber=new RegExp("\\d{7}", "g")` which passes a string, not a regexp literal, to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the digit part then try following..

`"ID=2".match(/\d+/)[0]`

**OR** just

`"ID=2".match(/\d+/)`

Comment: or simply: "ID=2".match(/\d+/);

Comment: @The Mask - ya that too would suffice.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if("ID=2".match(new RegExp(/ID\=(\d+)/)))
    alert("Matched" + RegExp.$1);
else
    alert("No Match");
```

Try that!

You need to use `String.match()`